# React Hooks : Invalid hook call while using useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have form with a submit button when I submit the form, I'm calling `lookup` function.
When the code complied to graphQl, It returns Invalid hooks error.

**Versions**

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

**Code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, Form, Input, Row, Card, Col } from "antd";
import { SearchOutlined, LoginOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { useQuery, useMutation, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const IDP_LOOKUP = gql`
  query getBusiness($name: String!) {
    business(name: $name) {
      id
      name
      domain {
        DomainType
        ... on Domains {
          DomainName
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const lookup = (values) => {
  let DomainName = "https://" + values.Orgname + ".com";

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(IDP_LOOKUP, {
    variables: {
      name: DomainName
    }
  });
};

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card size="small" title="Okta Login">
        <Row type="flex">
          <Col lg={24}>
            <Form name="lookup_login" className="login-form" onFinish={lookup}>
              <Row gutter={16} align="center" justify="center" type="flex">
                <Col lg={18}>
                  <Form.Item
                    label="Org Name"
                    name="Orgname"
                    rules={[
                      {
                        required: true,
                        message: "Please enter org name!"
                      }
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Input addonBefore="https://" addonAfter=".com" />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Col>
                <Col lg={6}>
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button
                      type="primary"
                      htmlType="submit"
                      className="login-form-button"
                    >
                      <SearchOutlined /> Lookup
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Error:**

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling useQuery from within an event handler.

Comment: @fynmnx Could you please update the code

Comment: Working on an answer...

Comment: can you share you complete code or github link, to enable us help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo has a [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery) hook that you can call after the component has rendered. This returns a tuple where the first item is a function you can then call from your handler to actually perform the query.

I think something like this should work:

```
const Login = () => {    
  const [lookupIdp, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(IDP_LOOKUP);

  const lookup = (values) => {
    let DomainName = "https://" + values.Orgname + ".com";

    lookupIdp({
      variables: {
        name: DomainName
      }
    })
  };

  return (
      <div>
```

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you are also trying to use the hook outside of your component. Updated my answer to show where the handler and hook call should live.

Comment: `unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.`  getting this warning

Comment: That sounds like somehow the query is being run prematurely maybe? Perhaps the lookup handler is being called while the component is rendering somehow? I would need to see more I think to help with that.

Comment: Are you getting that warning during component render or after submitting the form?

Comment: I did not see that warning now. I will keep monitoring. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn be calling hooks/lookup function inside your Login component, you can declare constant variables outside the function, but not hook.

```
const Login = () => {
  const lookup = (values) => {
    let DomainName = "https://" + values.Orgname + ".com";

    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(IDP_LOOKUP, {
      variables: {
        name: DomainName
     }
  });

 return <></>
};
```

You get the idea? Though your code is incomplete, for a better explanation, because I can't see your on change handler

Comment: I'm not sure this is right either. The `useQuery` should be a statement at the top level of the react component (<Login/>). I think you should place the useQuery there, and use `enabled` to issue the query when you actually have the data you need to issue it (see here: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/dependent-queries)

Comment: Oh nevermind. I thought this was using react-query, not apollo...

Comment: @chukwu3meka After the code change, I'm getting same issue.

Comment: can I see where you're handling form value change?

Comment: on form submit `onFinish={lookup}`

Comment: The hook call should live at the top level of the component (hooks should never be called conditionally). This is why apollo has a lazy version of the hook so you can trigger it after the component has rendered.

Comment: can you share you complete code or github link, to enable us help?